# Java FileIO Error not analyzing all class

Tags: java, file-io, iterator

I am trying to create a jar file which analyzes all files in a directory in look for the provided String and replaces it with the provided string + .getInstance(), I have this code:

```
public static String toAnalyze;
    public static String path;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java InstanceFixer <To Analyze> <Path>" );
            System.exit(1);
        }

        toAnalyze = args[0];
        path = args[1];

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        Date resultDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        LoggingUtils.log("Instance Fixer","Started InstanceFixer on analysis " + toAnalyze + " at " + sdf.format(resultDate));

        startIterating();
    }

    public static void startIterating() {
        File dir = new File(path);
        System.out.println(dir);
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                    filterFile(child);
            }
            LoggingUtils.log("Iterator","Analyzed " + directoryListing.length + " files.");
        } else {
            LoggingUtils.log("Iterator", path + " is not valid \n won't be able to Analyze files (if any).");
        }
    }

    public static void filterFile(File file) {
      try {
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
          BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
          String read = in.readLine();
              if (read.contains(toAnalyze + "Manager")) {
                  out.write(read.replace(toAnalyze + "Manager", toAnalyze + "Manager.getInstance()"));
                  LoggingUtils.log("Filter","Analyzed file " + file.getName() + ", found and fixed instance.");
                  out.close();
              } else {
                  LoggingUtils.log("Filter","Analyzed file " + file.getName() + ", didn't find anything to rename, skipped.");
              }
          in.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          LoggingUtils.log("Filter","There was a problem: " + e);
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

The problem is that it is only searching on the first or last line and instead of replacing the text it writes it to the side of the old one. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> instead of replacing the text it writes it to the side of the old one

In `new FileWriter(file, true)` parameter `true` is setting `append` option means that writer will add new content at the end of file. Setting it to `false` on the other hand means that file will be cleaned and writer will start writing it from beginning (which is probably not what you want if it contains more than one lines).

But anyway you shouldn't read and write to the same file you are analysing at the same time.
 Instead

- create new temporary file,
- iterate over all lines of your original file,
- write lines to temporary file - with changes you wanted.
- remove original file
- rename temporary file to have same name as original one.

Example: lets say we want to add line new column with line numbers so in fact we want to edit each line and add at its start something like `xxx:` where `x` represents number (or space if number doesn't have three digits). So we can do it like

```
try {
    File original = new File("input.txt");
    File tmp = new File("tmp.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(original));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter(tmp)));
    String line = null;
    int i = 1;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        out.format("%3d: %s%n", i++, line);// %d digit, %s string, %n
                                            // line separator
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();

    // lets swap files
    if (original.delete()) {
        System.out.println("original file removed");
        if (tmp.renameTo(original)) {
            System.out
                    .println("temporary file renamed to original file");
        } else {
            System.out.println("temporary file couldn't be renamed");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("original file couldn't be removed");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @user3241491 Added example. It is not exactly same thing you wanted to accomplish but should give you base idea.

Comment: @user3241491 actually last part (replacing original file with temporary one containing new version of data) can be shortened using `Files.copy(tmp.toPath(), original.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`